PostfixのSTARTTLS設定方法と、確認方法についての質問
Alma Linux 8の環境にPostfix 3.5.8を導入し、送信専用のメールサーバを構築しました。
このメールサーバは既に本番環境として稼働しております。
DKIM, DMARCの対応で、現状把握のためにgmailにメールを送信したところ、
メールTLS化ができておらず、メールには「暗号化されませんでした」と表示されました。
いろいろな記事を読んで暗号化設定手順について確認しているのですが、
以下のページ等を参考にすると、下記の設定してpostfixのデーモンをreloadすればよいと理解できました。
Postfix SMTP メールリレー MTA 送信に TLS を利用する (Rocky Linux)

smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1


構築した環境の /etc/postfix/main.cf を確認すると、下記の通りの設定でした。
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_security_level = may

質問1
暗号化してメール送信するようにするには、上記設定にあわせればよいか？
（smtp_tls_CAfile、smtp_tls_loglevel の定義が悪さをしているのか？）
質問2
VirtualBox等で、送信MTAと受信MTAをクローズ環境に構築し、検証環境として手順を事前に確かめたいのですが、メールサーバですと、SPFなどのDNSを参照して動くことから難しいのかと考えます。
メールサーバの検証環境構築に参考になる情報があれば教えていただければと思います。
postconfの結果等の必要な情報があれば、併せて御指摘いただければと思います。

少なくとも質問1は実際に試せば結果が分かりませんか？なお、smtp_tls_CAfile に指定するファイルはデフォルトで記述されている /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt と解説サイトの記載例 /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem の二通りありますが、実際にはどちらもシンボリックリンクで同じ /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem を参照しています (RHEL8 の環境で確認)

早速回答いただきありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、まずは試して確認してみます。本番稼働しているサーバなので、事前にある程度、この設定で問題ないこと確認したく質問１をさせていただきました。
ログの設定をすればもう少し状況が見えるかもしれません。
また、当方almalinux8の環境も
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
は、（/etc/pki/tls/cert.pemも同じ）/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pemへのシンボリックリンクでした。
